# docker python app failure: OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker

I am seeing this error from python code inside 6.8centos container

```
request = <SubRequest 'test_dir_resource_creation' for <Function 'test_instance_creation'>>

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
    def test_dir_resource_creation(request):
        """Create the test environment based on local or br env."""
>       user = os.getlogin()
E       OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device

tests/conftest.py:16: OSError
```

I read something online that it may be due to missing of mod_wsgi rpm so I've installed it but still no luck. Is it possible for docker to have tty to for the above python code to work?

Comment: Do your kernel's match?

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins sorry, how do i check that please?

Comment: What is the host's OS?

Comment: rhel7.4 and my container is centos6.8